# after I change composer.json file Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

after I change composer.json file below errors are displayed. how can I fix it?

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "consoletvs/charts": "5.*",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "genealabs/laravel-caffeine": "^0.7.1",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.7.*" //I changed this line
},
```

[image: this errors came with changes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this in your `composer.json` file:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "^5.7"
```

Then update composer: `composer update`

add your new provider to the `providers` array of `config/app.php`:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

add two class `aliases` to the aliases array of `config/app.php`:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Comment: But artisan is not worked yet,
Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Comment: @ChaminThilakarathne check and try updated answer now